# Get error-generating function name in set_error_handler callable

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm setting a custom error handler in php, like this:

```
<?php  

function custom_error_handler($severity, $message, $file, $line, $errcontext) 
{
    //Need to get function name
    echo sprintf("\n%s [%s@L%s] : %s \n", $severity, $file, $line, $message);
}

function test_error() 
{
    trigger_error("Just a user generated error");
}

set_error_handler( function($severity, $message, $file, $line, $errcontext) {
    custom_error_handler($severity, $message, $file, $line, $errcontext);
} );

test_error();
```

Is there some way, inside the scope of `custom_error_handler` to get the function name that triggered / generated the error, in this case `test_error()`

I've read in the docs [debug_backtrace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) but I'm not sure if  that is the way to go.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: `set_error_handler('custom_error_handler')`. There's no use for the anonymous function wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in that case debug_backtrace is what you need but you also need to know what you really want to trace.

Look at sample code:

```
<?php  

function custom_error_handler($severity, $message, $file, $line, $errcontext) 
{
      $dt = debug_backtrace();
      $function = '';      

      $remove = array(__FUNCTION__,'trigger_error', '{closure}');

       foreach ($dt as $dti) {
             if (isset($dti['function']) && !in_array($dti['function'],$remove)) {
                 $function = $dti['function'];
                 break;
             }

       }


    //Need to get function name
    echo sprintf("\n%s [%s@L%s@%s] : %s \n", $severity, $file, $line, $function, $message)."<br />";


}

function test_error() 
{
    trigger_error("Just a user generated error");
}

set_error_handler( function($severity, $message, $file, $line, $errcontext) {
    custom_error_handler($severity, $message, $file, $line, $errcontext);
} );

function bla_error() {
    test_error();    
}

bla_error();
trigger_error("Just a user generated error");
test_error();
```

In this case you get returned:

```
1024 [D:\DaneAplikacji\easyphp\data\localweb\error.php@L27@test_error] : Just a user generated error
1024 [D:\DaneAplikacji\easyphp\data\localweb\error.php@L39@] : Just a user generated error
1024 [D:\DaneAplikacji\easyphp\data\localweb\error.php@L27@test_error] : Just a user generated error
```

So in both cases for bla_error and test_error you get function test_error because in this function finally trigger_error is launched but when you don't use **break** you get final function which launched test_error (if any)

I personally used backtrace_ignore in DB class when I wanted to save queries with name of file and line where the query was launched with code:

```
private function fetchLauncher() 
{
  $key = 0;     
  $dt = debug_backtrace();

  for ($i=0,$c=count($dt);$i<$c;++$i) {
   if (strpos($dt[$i]['file'],$this->settings['backtrace_ignore'])===false) {
     $key = $i;
     break;  
   }      
  }


   $this->launcher['file'] = $dt[$key]['file'];
   $this->launcher['line'] = $dt[$key]['line'];              
}
```

(as $this->settings['backtrace_ignore'] I had name of my DB class filename to find the proper file).